# How to prove that $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{n} j(j + 1) = \frac{1}{3}n(n + 1)(n + 2)\ \text{where }\ n \geq 1.$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, education

I would like to know how it is to prove this problem:

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n} j(j + 1) = \frac{1}{3}n(n + 1)(n + 2)  \text{where } n \geq 1 \\
$$

Comment: Split it into the sums $\sum j^2$ and $\sum j$.

Comment: Have you considered using induction?

Comment: @JacobCheverie I have to solve the problem by induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using induction, prove the case $n = 1:$

If $n = 1$, we wish to show $$\sum_{j = 1}^{1}j(j + 1) = \dfrac{1}{3}(1)(1+1)(1+2)$$ which is obviously true.

Now we assume the initial statement is true and wish to show that this holds for $n + 1$ and we are done. In other words, show

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n + 1}j(j+1) = \dfrac{1}{3}(n+1)((n+1)+1)((n+1)+2)$$
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n + 1}j(j+1) = \dfrac{1}{3}(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$$

It's obvious that the extended sum is the initial sum plus the added term:

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n + 1}j(j+1) = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}j(j+1) + \sum_{j = n + 1}^{n+1}j(j+1)$$

And we are assuming the initial sum to be true as part of our induction argument. Therefore, by substitution:
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n + 1}j(j+1) = \dfrac{1}{3}(n)(n+1)(n+2) + \sum_{j = n + 1}^{n+1}j(j+1)$$
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n + 1}j(j+1) = \dfrac{1}{3}(n)(n+1)(n+2) + (n+1)((n+1)+1)$$
$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n + 1}j(j+1) = \dfrac{1}{3}(n)(n+1)(n+2) + (n+1)(n+2)$$

If you expand the right hand side of what you wish to show and multiply this final line all the way out, you will see the connection. Factoring at the end will not help you. For a formal proof just work your way down one side and back up the other.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} j^2 = \frac {1} {6}  n(n+1) (2n+1)$$ and $$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} j = \frac {n(n+1)} {2}.$$

**EDIT** $:$

To prove the first sum consider the equality $(t+1)^3 - t^3 = 3t^2 + 3t +1.$ Take $t=1,2, \cdots, n.$ Then we get by summing the equality for $t=1,2, \cdots,n$ $$3\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n} t^2 = \sum\limits_{t=1}^{n} ((t+1)^3 - t^3) - 3 \left ( \sum\limits_{t=1}^{n} t \right ) - n.$$

Can you proceed now?

What is $\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n} ((t+1)^3 - t^3)$?

Observe that  $\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n} ((t+1)^3 - t^3) = (n+1)^3 -1.$ Also you know that $\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n} t = \frac {n(n+1)} {2}.$ Now you should plug all these things to get the required answer.

So $$\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n}t^2 = \frac 1 3 \left ((n+1)^3 - 1 - \frac {3n(n+1)} {2}  - n \right ).$$

I leave the further simplifications to you.

Comment: I just want to see how it is concluded if it can be proven or not.

Comment: By the way can you see it now @Chris Michael?

Comment: Which one has to be proved??

Comment: I'm really learning about this topic, and I wanted to take that exercise as a reference

Comment: Do you know the above two well known sums mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Yep, I know that the second equation is the sum of 1 to n, but of the first I have no idea.

Comment: Well I will prove it then. Wait!

Comment: Have you understood now @Chris Michael?

Comment: Sorry, it is something triki for me to understand for now the whole concept of the question you formulated now.

Comment: Which one is tricky to you?

Comment: ∑t=t=1 to n ((t+1)^3−t^3)

Comment: Try to observe that $\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n} ((t+1)^3 - t^3) = (n+1)^3 - 1.$ It's a telescoping sum. Have you noticed that?

Comment: Each term is canceled, correct?

Comment: Now can you proceed @Chris Michael??

Comment: Not really, apologies. I'm learning now hehe

Comment: What you can't follow?

Comment: I cant follow the last equation that you propose.

Comment: Do you agree that for all $t$ we have $(t+1)^3 - t^3 = 3t^2+3t+1$ or not? If you agree then take sum in both sides of the above equality for $t=1$ to $t=n.$ Then what will you end up with?